# How best to display notifications on the front-end using caught exceptions as an example

Tags: notifications

I'm using exceptions in my plugin.

```
function foo() {
    // Some code.
    throw new Exception( 'Division by 0' );
    // Code continued.
}

try {
    echo foo();
} catch ( Exception $e ) {

}
```

I'm aware `$e->getMessage()` will give me the caught exception's message, but in the absence of a notifications API, what is the recommended way to display this message to the user on the front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For admin area you can use admin_notices:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices

For public area (front end) you would probably need to output to some hook and insert the proper CSS. You could use wp_footer() for that, which is present in every theme (or at least should be) and is inside the body tag.

Comment: `wp_head` is triggered in the `<head>` section. I think notification messages _should_ be displayed in the body? But I'm now thinking which body template hook is guaranteed to always be there?

Comment: Ok, my fault. Use wp_footer (it's inside body) and it's used by every theme (or at least should be used). From there you can just insert a message with a fixed animation at top, or a lightbox ;)